# Bring your questions out from Area51

Tags: discussion

I think people should post their sample questions from proposal stage, out on the Beta site.

Everyone probably invented their sample questions, but they were upvoted as being good questions. I think those of you who took the time to think up a good question deserve the points for the effort you put in!

Is posting proposal Qs to the Beta frowned on by SE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those example questions represent actual problems you have; great. Post away.

But you have to be *really* be careful about *staging* questions you already know the answer to, or *faking* problems you don't actually have… just to fill the site with *sample* data. **This is a live site with real people** spending their real time and their hard-earned knowledge to help people they feel need their help. If there's a sense that that the users don't really need the help they are asking for, **the whole exercise would likely be perceived as a waste of time.**

Please, at least read

[**Your New Site: Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

This is a dangerous game to build traffic on this site. I wouldn't try it, **especially so early in this site's development.**

Comment: The litmus tests for good questions are clear (on topic, answerable, etc.) No need to tack on an, "I think you made it up," test; If I could think up a good question every day, posted them here, they were upvoted, elicited answers which get upvoted, etc. -- that would be the very definition of good questions and would lead to an excellent knowledge repository in the site. (I'm not going to personally bringing them all out for the points.) I see no reason that people can't post their own, upvoted in the proposal, questions -- those questions are literally examples of what's on-topic here.

Comment: (ran out of chars) ...and there are several upvoted proposal questions for which I'd like to see the answers.

Answer (score 2):

We should go ahead and post good questions. No matter if their were from the proposal stage or not. Even no matter if we already know the answer (and possibly post it later on) or let our fellow users answer it. By asking, we show what kind of questions we would like to see when the site has gone live.

It also helps building our tag set.

If it's not clear if a question is a good fit, let's discuss it here on meta. This gives us agreements and statements to which we can refer later.

Comment: I'm un-accepting this. I think yours is the right answer, but I was hoping to generate more discussion. I'm hoping it will attract more attention if it has no accepted answer.

Comment: @CraigConstantine Sure, I understand, let it be open. Feel free to remove the comment as I saw it, I'll do the same. I'm for clean Q&A without much distraction ;-)